# Different symbology for each theme in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology

I want that a layer changes its symbology depending on the theme selected.

Is that possible?

Maybe if I could retrieve the name of the active theme I could add it as a part rule at the symbology.

```
If ThemeName == 'A'
...do this symbology
else
...do this one
```

There's a a way to get it?

Comment: Are you talking about map themes?

Comment: Yes for the canvas.

Comment: Read that : https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#configuring-map-themes , it should help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, @Javier G you can do it by combining themes with layer styles.
You assign a layer style to each theme.

**Do you know how to have several styles available for a layer?**

You set the style, then right click > styles > add...

This will open a dialog box where you can enter the name of the style.
Set another style and repeat the procedure by assigning another name.
[image]

This way you have multiple styles available for a layer, with a single click
[image]

Now, you can create several themes and assign a certain style to each layer.

Every time you change the theme, the styles of all the layers you have set up will change, so your whole map

[image]

Comment: That was exactly what I Was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad, you're welcome:)