# Setting specific layer colors in print layout using QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, print-composer, layouts

We are working on a quite complex task in QGIS containing multiple layer groups. We need to show the same layers in different print layouts, but with a different color scheme.

Is there a way to solve this without having to create layer copies with the alternative colors?

Comment: What have you tried? How do you define "best solution"? Is this a repetitive task? If it is repetitive, do the layers change?

Comment: In QGIS the same layer could have several symbology then with map theme you will be able to choose witch one is displayed in witch layout

Comment: Thank you. @Eric: No, the task is not repetitive.

Comment: @J.R: As I never needed this setting before, I thought I do such things within the print layouts. However, I found the solution here: [Different symbology for each theme in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/375883/different-symbology-for-each-theme-in-qgis). Like you say, of course: Define several symbology and select the right one for the respective map theme. Already asked for my question to be marked as a duplicate.